# Kafka streams - set a different time window depending on the message group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wonder if given a KStream, is possible to set a different time window depending on the message group, for example, for groupBy "A" 5 seconds, for groupBy "B" 10 seconds ...

```
KStream<String, Msg> stream = builder.stream(stringSerde, msgSerde, input);
stream.groupBy((key, msg) -> msg.getPool())
      .aggregate(init, agg, TimeWindows.of(wndLength).advanceBy(wndLength), msgSerde)
      ...
```

Comment: filter or branch before the groupby?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky You should put this as an answer. Branching before groupBy() sound reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way that comes to mind is to `.filter()` or `.branch()` before you `.groupBy()`/`.aggregate()`, like:

```
KStream<String, Msg> stream = builder.stream(stringSerde, msgSerde, input);
stream.filter((key, msg) -> msg.getPool().equals("A"))
      .groupBy((key, msg) -> msg.getPool())
      .aggregate(init, agg, TimeWindows.of(wndLength).advanceBy(wndLength), msgSerde)
      ...
```